# Why does Treeset<Object> contains() return false even if Object.equals() and Object.compareTo() are consistent?

Tags: java, treeset

I use a TreeSet to sort the `Task` objects in the game engine that I'm developing. I wrote the `compareTo()` method in `Task`, the `compare()` method in my custom `Comparator`(just to try, because it returns the value of `compareTo()`) and I wrote `equals()`(again, just to try).

```
...
Treeset set;
Task t;
...
System.out.println(t.compareTo(set.first()));
System.out.println(set.comparator().compare(t, set.first()));
System.out.println(t.equals(set.first()));
System.out.println(String.valueOf(set.contains(t)));
```

If I run this code I get this output:

```
0
0
true
false
```

What didn't I consider?

EDIT: here are the classes. I ran the output test instead of calling `queue.remove(t)`

```
class TaskQueue {
    private double taskTime;
    private TreeSet<TimedTask> queue;
    private ArrayList<TimedTask> toAddBuffer;

    public TaskQueue(double taskTime) {
        this();
        this.taskTime = taskTime;
    }

    public TaskQueue() {
        queue = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<TimedTask>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(TimedTask o1, TimedTask o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
            
        });
        toAddBuffer = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public double getTaskTime() {
        return taskTime;
    }

    public void setTaskTime(double taskTime) {
        double delay = taskTime - this.taskTime;
        this.taskTime = taskTime;
        for (TimedTask t : queue) {
            t.setTimeStamp(t.getTimeStamp() + delay);
        }
    }

    public void add(TimedTask t) {
        toAddBuffer.add(t);
    }

    private void add(TimedTask t, double millisecondDelay) {
        t.setTimeStamp(t.getTimeStamp() + (millisecondDelay * (Game.TIME_SCALE)));
        queue.add(t);
    }

    public void performTasks(double timestamp) {
        for (TimedTask task : toAddBuffer) {
            task.setTimeStamp(taskTime + task.getMilliseconds() * (Game.TIME_SCALE / 1000));
            queue.add(task);
        }
        toAddBuffer.clear();
        ArrayList<TimedTask> toRemoveBuffer = new ArrayList<>();
        TimedTask taskToAdd = null;
        boolean scheduledNew;
        do {
            scheduledNew = false;
            for (TimedTask t : queue) {
                if (timestamp < t.getTimeStamp()) {
                    taskTime = timestamp;
                    break;
                }
                t.perform();
                toRemoveBuffer.add(t);
                if (t.toReschedule()) {
                    taskToAdd = t;
                    scheduledNew = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (TimedTask t : toRemoveBuffer) {
                queue.remove(t);
            }
            toRemoveBuffer.clear();
            if (taskToAdd != null) {
                add(taskToAdd, taskToAdd.getMilliseconds());
                taskToAdd = null;
            }
        } while (scheduledNew);
    }
}

public abstract class TimedTask extends Task implements Comparable<TimedTask> {

    private double timeStamp;
    private double milliseconds;
    private boolean reschedule;

    public TimedTask(double delay) {
        this.milliseconds = delay;
    }

    double getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    void setTimeStamp(double timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public boolean toReschedule() {
        if (milliseconds == 0.0) {
            return false;
        }
        return reschedule;
    }

    public void setToReschedule(boolean toReschedule) {
        reschedule = toReschedule;
    }

    public double getMilliseconds() {
        return milliseconds;
    }

    public void setMilliseconds(double milliseconds) {
        this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
    }

    @Override
    public final int compareTo(TimedTask t) {
        if (this == t) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (timeStamp < t.timeStamp) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.getClass().equals(o.getClass()))
        
            return false;

        TimedTask that = (TimedTask) o;
        return this.compareTo(that) == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your `equals` and `compareTo` implementations. Also, why isn't your `TreeSet` parametrised with `Task`? It should be `TreeSet<Task>` (although, it's not the problem here).

Comment: and you also implemented `hashCode`, right? consistently with `equals` and `compareTo`?

Comment: @Eugene I don't think `hashCode` matters in a `TreeSet`

Comment: I'm sorry. I will edit to include the code of the actual classes

Comment: @AndrewVershinin if you did implement `equals`, you _must_ implement `hashCode`

Comment: Sadly the code didn't work even before I implemented equals

Comment: 1) that is one weird way to implement `equals`2) as said - implement `hashCode` also 3) your fields that make up `equals/hashCode/compareTo` _must_ not be changed after you placed these objects into a hash based collection.

Comment: @Eugene I can just remove equals, right? I used the implementation from another question. And I'm not changing the timeStamp before I remove the Task to add it again. Or am I?

Comment: @Eugene while it is true that you need equals and hashCode together, a TreeSet just uses compareTo, it's a bit broken for a Set but the documentation talks about it.

Comment: I agree you should implement `hashCode`, however is not used by `TreeSet` or the underlying `TreeMap`. On the other hand, `equals` is required. That being said, I recommend using a priority queue instead of a TreeMap due to the possibility of task rescheduling and the inevitability of the tree becoming lopsided.

Comment: @matt agreed. the problem is that you want to be consistent - that is a good habit to grow; in general.

Comment: @Eugene @matt, As mentioned by @Locke, Though it a good practice to add `hashCode` (even should be made mandatory compilation check), `hashCode` is primarily used in bucketing data structures like `HashMap`. Even TreeMap does not need `hashCode`

Comment: @Locke @Eugene @matt, In `TreeMap`, `equals` is needed only for `containsValue` check. Only `compareTo` is enough for `containsKey` check(equals can return anything, always `false`). Alternatively only `equals` is needed for `containsValue` and `hashCode` or `compareTo` can be any random value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public final int compareTo(TimedTask t) {
    if (this == t) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (timeStamp < t.timeStamp) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This is outright incorrect.  It can be -- and is, in your example -- the case that `timeStamp == t.timeStamp` but `this != t`.

Instead, write

```
@Override
public final int compareTo(TimedTask t) {
    return Integer.compare(timeStamp, t.timeStamp);
}
```

Comment: I can't unless I change the way I organize my Tasks. Different Tasks can have the same timestamp. Should I use another data type instead of TreeSet?

Comment: @grecLon Yes, because a TreeSet uses compareTo, so if you're comparing by timestamp then two objects with the same timestamp are equal in a TreeSet. Why are you using a Set at all?

Comment: Because its iteration order is guaranteed. What data structure could I use? Should I just sort a list every time I add a Task?

Comment: @grecLon Yes, why not? If you need the iteration order maintained for repeatable usages a list sounds like a reasonable solution. If you find performance problems with an ArrayList, then you could search for a better implementation.

Comment: It sounds like the appropriate data structure may be a priority queue, from your code sample: you only have to get the elements out in sorted order, you don't need them 100% sorted at all times.

Comment: In any event, the change I have suggested is, really, the only way to make a `TreeSet` work correctly, even if it doesn't satisfy the use case you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override methods `hashCode` and `equals`. If you don't know how to implement find out on stack or google it.

In contains is checks method `hashCode`, if is false, then `equals`.

Your implementation of `compareTo` is wrong.

```
if (this == t) {
    return 0;
}
```

This check if object is this same as comparing.

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = new Foo();
bollean result = foo1 == foo2;
```

Above gets always false, because foo1 and foo2 is not this same obeject. Is equals, but not this same.
Anyway `double` is not good type to comparing. Better is use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I wrote that because I only need to know if they are the same object. Different tasks can have the same timestamp but if I do this and I compare them I get 0 from compare and the wrong task is removed. Is it wrong?

Comment: better is use generated uuid `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` or some id, and check is equals